# Why does this textbox binding example work in WPF but not in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

Why is it in the following **silverlight** application that when I:

- change the default text in the **first** textbox
- move the cursor to the **second** text box (i.e. **take focus off** first textbox)
- click the **button**

that inside the **button handler**, the property `InputText` still has the old value "default text"?

**What do I have to do to get the binding to work in Silverlight? The same code works fine in WPF.**

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestUpdate123.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
  <StackPanel Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

          <TextBox 
        Text="{Binding InputText}"
        Height="200"
        Width="600"
        Margin="0 0 0 10"/>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Content="Convert" Click="Button_Convert_Click" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox 
        Height="200"
        Width="600"
        Margin="0 0 0 10"/>

        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding OutputText}"/>

        </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestUpdate123
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region ViewModelProperty: InputText
        private string _inputText;
        public string InputText
        {
            get
            {
                return _inputText;
            }

            set
            {
                _inputText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("InputText");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ViewModelProperty: OutputText
        private string _outputText;
        public string OutputText
        {
            get
            {
                return _outputText;
            }

            set
            {
                _outputText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OutputText");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            InputText = "default text";
        }


        private void Button_Convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OutputText = InputText;
        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explicitly specify TwoWay binding on the first textbox does that fix it?

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Height="200"
    Width="600"
    Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems as though I just need to define the **Mode=TwoWay** and it works:

```
Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Strange that it works in WPF without explicitly specifying Mode=TwoWay.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx

OneWay is default in Silverlight, it would appear. My hunch is at least for text boxes, TwoWay is default in WPF.